# Подключение js-скриптов в Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, spring, frontend, thymeleaf

Проблема состоит в том, что не могу понять как правильно подключить внешний файл **js** к **html**.
Моя структура проекта выглядит так:

- resources
- static
- search.js

Вроде бы проблем как таких быть не должно, *js* файл состоит в папке *static*, код работает(потому что при размещении в html тег **script** все работает отлично).

Мои попытки подключения выглядят следующим образом:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/search.js" th:src="@{/search.js}"></script>
<script src="../static/search.js" th:src="|${}/search.js|"></script>
<script th:src="|${}/search.js|"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{search.js}"></script>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Нашел решение.**

Проблема была в том, что подключение происходило в теге *head*, что *thymeleaf* посчитал недопустимым и не подгружал их.

**Решение состоит в том**, чтобы разместить подключение внешних скриптов перед закрывающим тегом body, валидное подключение:

```
<!-- Connecting external js-files -->
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/search.js}"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Очень жалко что вы отметели ваш, как вы правильно сказали "бред", как ответ. Кто-то может подумать что это именно так и сделать тоже, а не найти настоящую проблему. Я не видел ваш код, но скорее всего файл не загружался потому что были предыдущие ошибки. вы не захотели тратить время чтобы найти их, и это ваше право, но не стоит предлогать это другим. Подумайте , может стоит удалить ваш "ответ"?

Comment: Вы не правы в этом, в коде все отлично, я просто не понимаю связь между подключением именно в конце тега body, поэтому так и начал. Как раз таки - это решение.

Comment: @AndriiSukhetskiy, `thymeleaf` все равно где именно Вы размещаете тег `<script>`, в `head` или в `body`. Я предположу, проблема Ваша заключалась не столько в подключении, сколько в том, что подключенные скрипты начинали работать не дожидаясь загрузки страницы и пытались работать с элементами, которых еще не существует. Именно поэтому Вы не видели никаких результатов при подключении в хеаде и увидели их после подключения в конце страницы. Поэтому Ваш ответ сверху назвали не совсем корректным (с чем я и согласен).

Comment: Почитайте про `DOMContentLoaded`. попробуйте перенести интересующий ваш код в колбек, ожидающий загрузку страницы `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { /** >>> ВОТ СЮДА  <<<  */ })`; а потом можете обратно переносить подключение скрипта в head

Comment: Смысл претензии  @SlavaIvanov, в том что у Вас есть несколько проблем. Допустим у Вас есть `проблема А` и `проблема Б` и у них есть решения: `решение A1`, `решение Б1`. Но Вы указали в посте только одну `проблему А` и в качестве её решения указали только  `решение Б1`. Что является некорректным для стороннего читателя, хотя Вашу проблему это может решать. Но пользователь, который столкнулся только с одной `проблемой А` просто запутается в Вашем решении и оно ему не столько поможет, сколько навредит.

Comment: Спасибо @МихаилРебров ваш коментарий, это все что я хотел сказать (пометил +1) и даже больше. В следующем коментарии вы даёте правильный ответ, как работать с проблемой автора. А автору все-таки стоит попробвать решить эту проблему предложенным способом. Скорее всего вы будете довольны результатом.